# Python: Change multi-line json String to single line

Tags: python, json

I have to pass the below string to a python command

```
'[{
  "action": "DELETE",
  "is_enabled": true,
  "name": "qe_ta_rule_kYKco6_ObjectLifecyclePolicy",
  "object_name_filter": null,
  "time_amount": 1,
  "time_unit": "DAYS"
}]'
```

Is there a way to replace all the newline characters so that i becomes a 1 line String

Comment: `.replace("\n", "")`?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid python string:

```
'[{
  "action": "DELETE",
  "is_enabled": true,
  "name": "qe_ta_rule_kYKco6_ObjectLifecyclePolicy",
  "object_name_filter": null,
  "time_amount": 1,
  "time_unit": "DAYS"
}]'
```

Multi-line strings should be like:

```
'[{ \
  "action": "DELETE", \
  "is_enabled": true, \
  "name": "qe_ta_rule_kYKco6_ObjectLifecyclePolicy", \
  "object_name_filter": null, \
  "time_amount": 1, \
  "time_unit": "DAYS" \
}]'
```

If this is coming from the web, it probably is coming like: `'[{ \n "action": "DELETE", \n ...'`

Either way, you would replace the new lines like `your_str.replace('\n', '')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jq` to achieve this:

Source JSON:

```
[
  {"empid": "1", "empname": "E1", "empsal": "100"},
  {"empid": "2", "empname": "E2", "empsal": "200"},
  {"empid": "3", "empname": "E3", "empsal": "300"}
]
```

Transformation:

```
cat source.json | jq -c '.[]' > target.json
```

Target JSON:

```
{"empid":"1","empname":"E1","empsal":"100"}
{"empid":"2","empname":"E2","empsal":"200"}
{"empid":"3","empname":"E3","empsal":"300"}
```